# The use of "Not only"

Tags: sentence-construction, word-choice, usage

Which of these sentence are correct and sound better?

> 1. I not only don't care whether he wins, I don't want to know about it either.
> 2. I not only don't care whether he wins, but I don't want to know about it either.
> 3. I not only don't care whether he wins, I neither want to know about it.
> 4. Not only don't I care whether he wins.
>      4.1 I don't... either.
>      4.2 But I don't ... either.
>      4.3 I neither.

Answer (score 2):

The canonical sentence structure is:

> "Not only … but also"

You can form this sentence as follows:

> "I not only don't care whether he wins but I also don't want to know about it either"

After reading them a few times **example one seems the best**.

- Two won't work since the second part is strengthening the first statement, not contrasting it.

> But is used when you wish to stress contradiction between the halves of the statement. For example:
>
> > She said the book was blue, but I think that it's green.

[From EL&U Discussion](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/67678/correct-use-of-but-however-and-although)

- Three won't work because neither is only followed by one thing: not knowing. I think if we added two elements that we don't want the sentence will be ok.

> I not only don't care whether he wins, I neither want to see nor hear about it.

- Four won't work since the contraction expands to "Not only do not I care".

Should you want to use neither the following sentence would be appropriate:

Comment: Can you include "also" and "either" in the same sentence? I have never known this. I didn't understand exactly what you meant about two and four. I believe that sentence suggested by you is omitted.

Comment: @GhaithAlrestom I've added some more detail. I'm not sure about if also and either really should be added like that. I think you are right that "either" should be removed.

Comment: I disagree that the "canonical" form is "Not only...". That's just a more emphatic version.

Comment: @Araucaria If I understand you correctly you are saying that I should have included a pronoun in that template? I would agree that most usages of "Not only..." should include the pronoun. I wanted to emphasize that many sentences that have a "not only" use "but also" to join a second idea together.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but it's a guideline on how to express your ideas in English idiomatically. (I decided to post this after reading your comment under Phil's answer.)

As Phil suggested, the canonical structure of this pattern is: ***not only ... but also ...***

> *I **not only** don't care whether he wins **but** I **also** don't want to know about it either.*

Now, let's consider other options that you could use.

You have two ideas, both in negative:

> a) I don't care whether he wins.
>   b) I don't want to know about it.

Here are other possible alternatives, ranging from the most basic to the most literary ones (in my opinion).

> *I don't care whether he wins, **and** I don't want to know about it.*
>   *I don't care whether he wins, **and** I don't want to know about it 
>   **either**.*
>   *I don't care whether he wins, **neither do I** want to know about it.*
>   *I don't want to know whether he wins, **neither do I** care.*
>   *I **neither** care **nor** want to know whether he wins.*
>   ***Neither do I*** care whether he wins, **nor do I** want to know about it.
>   ***Neither do I*** want to know whether he wins, **nor do I** care.